# Можно ли отключить микрофон средствами js?

Tags: javascript, аудио

К ПК присоединена гарнитура с микрофоном, можно ли  написать веб-приложение, которое по нажатию на кнопку будет отключать/включать микрофон? 
Если не на js, то на чем это можно реализовать?

Comment: Почему нет? Прерываете поток, потом возвращаете его. А как - зависит от того, как у Вас приложение работает.

Comment: А можно наводку где поискать про то, как это сделать? В js вообще не шарю) спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй гуглить Web Speech Api. Пример в Mozilla:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API